# access to an NIH study

Tags: nih

I am trying to start a research using a study mentioned in a biometrics paper. The paper only provides the NIH study number but without the dataset. The study number starts as MH so, to be specific, it got support from NIMH I think.

I can easily get access to the study whose number starting as NCT, but I cannot find this study, which is supposed to be publicly available. (I have tried searching the NIMH website.)

Moreover, what I am really interested in is the trail or intervention in this study, instead of the mere observational data.

Has anyone ever done this before? It will be so nice of you if you can tell me how to get access to this study. I am going through other papers hoping to find a way.

Comment: Try contacting the authors...

Comment: @SolarMike Yeah I know :) but since the NIH data is supposed to be publicly available, I prefer finding the data by myself and set contacting the author as the last step to take.

Comment: The authors may have made prior assumptions on the data...

Comment: For randomized controlled trials of healthcare interventions, I don't think it's common to have the raw trial data published (i.e. the individual participants' data), even if it's anonymized, due to privacy issues. I would imagine this should extend to your type of research. This is unfortunate. I don't know if the privacy issues are genuinely insurmountable or not.